# FFMPEG: rtsp stream to a udp stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I am looking for advice on using ffmpeg to convert RTSP stream to udp stream. What would be the simplest general command to do so? This is what I have right now:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.1.247/play1.sdp -f mpegts -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec mp2 udp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

The error I'm getting:

> UDP timeout, retrying TCP
>
> method PAUSE failed: 405 PAUSE
>
> rtsp://192....: operation not permitted
>
> Finishing stream 0:0 without any data written to it.

I'm running `ubuntu 14.04`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the ffmpeg command you are using good enough. I suspect your RTSP input stream is not valid. Have you verified it? You can do so using below command or in vlc also:

```
ffplay -i rtsp://192.168.1.247:port/filename
```

One change in the command could be instead of play1.sdp, you can directly give the stream filename i.e, a playable stream than sdp file. Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, i've originally been using vlc which works, but it keeps crashing after a while. Using that command you gave, it hangs when the status characters come up.

Comment: Here is the rtsp stream information: h264 90k, tbr, 90k, tbn, 180k, tbc; aac, 16kHz, mono, fltp